# ECS: Cluster is not starting one-off tasks on EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition

We have a particular cluster that we've only ever used for one-off tasks that are started via schedule on Fargate. We've clone one of our Fargate task-definitions to be EC2 (and then removed 'network mode', relying on the default) and then redeployed one of our scheduled-tasks to use it. However, its tasks are no longer being started. There are no immediately-failed tasks. Since it's not a 'service' there is no events-log to audit. Typically, we have our own task-tracking implemented by a lambda function that records when all containers are started and stopped, and there's nothing. We updated the new task-definition to use Fargate, and the tasks begin starting, so it's not a [obvious] flaw in the task-definition itself.

Note that we currently have two Fargate-specific capacity-providers and the only non-Fargate capacity-providers are autoscaling related (whereas we're talking about one-off tasks, not services where ASGs are relevant). I suspect this has something to do with it but I have no idea what to do about it:

[image: capacity providers]

I know that EC2 and ECS tasks are supposed to be able to run on the same cluster concurrently, but this imbalance in the capacity providers doesn't make sense to me. Would I be able to delete these capacity providers without affecting our current Fargate tasks?

The new ECS instance:

[image: ECS instances]

Answer (score 0):

> Note that we currently have two Fargate-specific capacity-providers and the only non-Fargate capacity-providers are autoscaling related (whereas we're talking about one-off tasks, not services where ASGs are relevant).

This is the problem. First, ASGs are relevant for any ECS tasks that need to run, not just ECS services. You have to have an EC2 capacity provider for ECS to create an EC2 instance when one is needed for an ECS task to run on. This is not ECS Service specific at all. ECS Services have ECS Application auto-scaling, which is a totally separate thing from Capacity Provider EC2 auto-scaling. ECS Services will auto-scale based on some metric like number of inbound requests, CPU usage, etc. If/when the number of EC2 instances in the cluster is not sufficient to run the number of ECS tasks that ECS is trying to run, then the EC2 Capacity Provider kicks in to scale out the number of EC2 instances (using the EC2 ASG).

So the solution to your issue is to add an EC2 Capacity Provider to the ECS cluster.

---

> I know that EC2 and ECS tasks are supposed to be able to run on the same cluster concurrently, but this imbalance in the capacity providers doesn't make sense to me.

For tasks that request to run on Fargate, the Fargate capacity provider will be used. For tasks that request to run on EC2, the EC2 capacity provider will be used. There is no imbalance here.

> Would I be able to delete these capacity providers without affecting our current Fargate tasks?

No. If you do that, then all Fargate tasks in the cluster will stop running. You simply need to add an EC2 capacity provider to the cluster, and leave the Fargate capacity providers as they are.

Comment: How do I disable a cluster for Fargate tasks? Those CP's are disabled from being selected and removed like the ASG ones can be.

Comment: I'm not sure you can, since the option is disabled on the UI. You could try doing that through the CLI to see if it lets you.

Comment: I created the launch profile and ASG, but tasks still aren't dispatching to EC2. I forced a minimum of one system, but that didn't seem to help. It looks as if the instances aren't registering themselves with ECS. It seems as if there might be a requirement to a) use an ECS-optimized image (which seems obvious), and b) add a setup script to the EC2 instances provisioned by the ASG to set a cluster name into a config in /etc so that the instance knows where to register. I found (b) in a [much] older post; is there a better way to do this now?

Comment: Are you doing all this manually by manually creating the ASG, launch-profile, etc? ECS will setup all this for you automatically https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-ec2-cluster-console-v2.html

Comment: I did it manually in EC2 since I wanted to try and reuse the cluster, the UI washes its hands of any support when the cluster already exists, and I figured the console was equivalent to the EC2 UI. Maybe, though. I neglected to consider the console route being specifically ECS-flavored. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: So, yes. The capacity provider screen on the update of an existing cluster just has a link to the EC2 ASG panel. The link from your last note doesn't mention existing clusters or ECS. I also couldn't find anything online about creating an ECS-flavored ASG from the CLI. I went ahead and created a brand new cluster just to see what happened if I made sure to do it right (I think I might've reused an ASG last time), but tasks still aren't starting (successful or failed).

Comment: FYI, the EC2 instances are registering, at least. It'd be nice to understand how to create a proper ASG for a CP of an existing cluster, but maybe we can focus on just why the tasks aren't running and I can figure that out later.

Comment: Try following this guide to call the ECS API and obtain further debug information about the issue with the service placement https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-event-messages.html

Comment: Remember that this isn't service related. These are just one-off tasks either started manually or via the event-scheduler.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that. There will be an error message displayed somewhere on the failed task in the ECS UI. You may have to change the dropdown to show tasks that have stopped.

Comment: The whole thing was that there was no trace. They're not even being started. That's the enigmatic thing of it. So, a brand new cluster and a corresponding ASG and CP, a task-definition that specifies EC2, and a schedule that specifies the new cluster, and yet there's complete silence (audited by way of a Lambda function called for all start/stop container events, our normal task-tracking mechanism).

Comment: What state is the task in during all this time? Pending? Provisioning? And it stays in that state forever, until you delete it or something?

Comment: No tasks are created whatsoever. The moment I revert to use the original task-definition (which is set to use Fargate) on the original cluster, the scheduler starts starting them once again. I'm using Terraform, so I'm just changing/reverting these two things in two places, and then applying.

Comment: OK perhaps I was confused about your actual situation. I thought the tasks just weren't deploying to the EC2 servers. If no pending tasks are created at all then this sounds like a permission issue. You should look in CloudTrail for the RunTask calls that are failing to see if it shows any errors there.

Comment: Can't be. It's still using the same role that it is under Fargate. The only thing that changed is the task-definition (same role though) and the cluster. If there's no EC2 CP, *should* EC2-only tasks still be visible for the cluster, maybe perpetually in the "PROVISIONING" state and never transitioning to the "STARTED" state? I was thinking they might not even instantiate, but it seems like you're implying they will and just be stuck in limbo (at least until a CP is added). Currently, there is absolutely no evidence of their existence once I switch the TD and cluster values.

Comment: You say "can't be" and yet that is exactly what you describe is happening. Yes, I have absolutely seen ECS tasks stuck perpetually in the "provisioning" state because there were no EC2 instances registered with the cluster. And I thought that was what you were describing. However if you aren't seeing the tasks show up in the cluster at all, then you need to debug the API calls that you are using to create the tasks. If you have a Lambda function creating the tasks, then you need to have it print/log the response from the AWS API call to see what is happening.

Comment: The Cloudwatch/eventbus scheduler is creating the tasks. It's using the same role that we use for the Fargate tasks.

Comment: Then you need to look in CloudTrail for the failed API calls. That's where the error message will be that will tell you what the actual issue is.

Comment: That's good to know. Thank you for mentioning that.